# Connect remotely to EC2 MySql with Sqldbx

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I have sqldbx installed on my windows 10 64bit.
When I choose "new connection" I have DBMS type "MySQL" to choose.
At first I got errors for missing Dlls but I overcame it.

My sqldbx is installed on Ubuntu in AWS EC2 instance.
It has a db and it's working well with my site and using phpmyadmin.
I guess my MySql is not configured for remote connections.
I tried to add a line in mysql configuration to bind to the external ip but not only it didn't work remotely, it also broke the internal connection and site didn't work well.

Anyone can help please?
Thanks!

Comment: First, comment out the bind address line in my.cnf.  Secondly, you have to grant access to your user at your windows ip address.  MySQL security is a combination of a user and an ip address / domain / hostname.  So, tgray@'ip1' is a completely different user than tgray@'ip2'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my my.cnf has no bind address line, it only has those 2 lines:
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

I didn't get the part about the windows' user ip, can you please clarify?
I remind you that sqldbx (my sql client) is on windows, the server is Ubuntu EC2

Comment: A mysql user consists of two parts, a name and an ip address, hostname or domain.  Two things have to happen to enable connections:  1 - the EC2 instance (database) has to be set up to enable remote connections.  One way to check is to login locally and type "show variables like 'bind%';"  If it comes back null or "*", it is set up for remote connections.  And 2:  the user@windows-ip-address must be created to allow access to the DB. Windows IP is the address of the sqldbx machine.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the configuration file is NOT named my.cnf and that's why mine didn't have the bind data.

The RIGHT file is here:
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

Once I comment out the bind line (and I know it's security issue, it's temp) I was able to connect remotely using the external IP and default port 3306.
In order to connect with root you need to run this first:
mysqladmin -u root -p pass

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' with grant option;

Cheers!